# Clean way to Compare / Copy between Similar Classes

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, accessor

We have two classes that have the exact same public accessors (and many of them) but are from different areas in the object hierarchy; we have a need to copy and compare between these two objects.  We could manually write a copy constructor and a comparison operator which compares the values of the same-named accessors, but it seems as though there's got to be a better way to do this using reflection and LINQ.

Example: we have class ClassA which has 70 accessors; we also have class ClassB which has 70 accessors, which are defined to be the same name and type as ClassA's accessors.

```
public class ClassA 
{
int OneInt {get; set;}
int TwoInt {get; set;}
...
string OneString {get; set;}
string AnotherString {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
int OneInt {get; set;}
int TwoInt {get; set;}
...
string OneString {get; set}
string AnotherString {get; set;}
}
```

What I'd like is a simple way of using reflection to discover all of the public accessors of ClassA, and use those names to set the values of the respective accessor on ClassB to the value of the accessor on ClassA.  Roughly, in psuedocode:

```
foreach (string accName in ClassA.Accessors[])
    BInstance.Accessors[accName].Value = AInstance.Accessors[accName].Value;
```

And, of course, the same thing could be used for testing equality between the two classes.  My knowledge of C# reflection and LINQ is not good enough to know how to get this done, but I'd swear it's something relatively simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your rough pseudocode is somewhat accurate. Let me clean it up a little:

```
foreach (var propertyA in typeof(ClassA).GetProperties())
{
    var propertyB = typeof(ClassB).GetProperty(propertyA.Name);
    var valueA = propertyA.GetValue(objectA, null);
    propertyB.SetValue(objectB, valueA, null);
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't do error checking, and stuff like that, but it should do the job.

You could do it in Linq, but I don't think it would be cleaner.

Comment: I like that one; that's very clear.  I knew I was in the right ballpark with the pcode!  :)

Answer (score 5):

How about using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>();
```

and then:

```
ClassA classA = ...
ClassB classB = Mapper.Map<ClassA, ClassB>(classA);
```

It's basically an implementation of your pseudo-code.

Comment: Nice; that's definitely an option, although I still have a lingering suspicion that there's a "clever" way to get this done in vanilla C#.

Comment: Yes of course, it would be to use reflection. But if you want it to be really clever (handle cases of null for example, incompatible types, ...) you will need to write lots of vanilla C# code. So why writing it when someone already did it, tested it, documented it, packaged it in a reusable assembly, measured its performance, ... so that you can now focus on the real business of your application instead of doing plumbing?

Comment: Your point is well taken, but I think there's value in learning techniques even when they're possibly already implemented in external libraries; it's a question of gaining depth with the language in a practical manner.

Comment: @McWafflestix, totally agree with. It's good for academic purposes. But in a real world application which is what I thought you were asking about I would think twice before writing all this code :-)

Comment: interesting point; this is actually for unit test code, so any failures are immediately caught and not for production use, but your point is well taken; I'd be cautious using this in actual production code without extensive edge case testing.